# Mongoose fails to reconnect after replicaset not found error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, replicaset

I'm running a small website that connects to MongoDB Atlas. It has a replicaset with 3 members. For the most part, everything works just fine, but every now an then Atlas' replicaset crashes (or something?) and Mongoose stops working from then on. It throws a single error - `MongoError: no primary found in replicaset` and that's it.

It doesn't fire `mongoose.connection.on('error')`, and no errors are reported after this point. It just fails to return any data.

It's sort of hard for me to debug this, as this is running in production, and I have no way of telling when replicaset will fail. Here's how I connect:

```
function connect() {
  tries++;
  mongoose.Promise = Promise;
  const { uri, options } = config.mongoDb;
  return mongoose.connect(uri, options);
}

let db = connect();
db
    .connection
    .on('error', (err) => {
        Raven.captureException(err);
        db.disconnect();
    })
    .on('disconnected', () => {
        db = connect();
    });
```

And my options look like this:

```
options: {
  server: {
    autoReconnect: true,
    ssl: true,
    poolSize: 10,
    socket_option: {
      keepAlive: true
    }
  }
}
```

Has anyone had similar problems before? Any idea what I'm doing wrong here, or how to actually catch the error, so I can properly reconnect?

Comment: What version of mongoose are you using? A replica set election should not result in connection error, since this error is only triggered when first connecting to the replica set. Mongoose should automatically reconnect. Could you try the script provided in https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2603#issuecomment-101301944 and see if you see any error except `null`?

Comment: I'm using ^4.6.1. It's really hard to test this as it's only happening in production, and it's very random when it stops working.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the latest version (currently 4.13.9)? The issue might have been fixed in the newer updates.